# How to pass a Presenter instance to two activities in Android using MVP pattern

Tags: android, android-activity

I am attempting to implement the MVP pattern in a new Android application. I have two activities, and have defined two View interfaces, one for each of the activities. For example:

```
public class MyWindow1 implements IView1
public class MyWindow2 implements IView2
```

And I have a common Presenter class:

```
public class MainPresenter implements Serializable {
public MainPresenter() {
}

public void setView1(IView1 view1) {
    this.view1 = view1;
}

public void setView2(IView2 view2) {
    this.view2 = view2;
}
```

This is all fairly straightforward so far. Now, the activities register with the presenter when they are first created, for example for view1:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_menu);

    mainPresenter = new MainPresenter();
    mainPresenter.setView1(this);
}
```

However, I have a problem now - I need to be able to create activity 2 (i.e. view2) and register it with the Presenter. But I cannot do this as the only (it seems?) way to pass objects between activities is the incredibly impractical method of using serialization. Which doesn't work in this case because I have the references back to the views, which would get lost during serialization.

How can I llink a single presenter to two views, ideally without just declaring the presenter as a static global, which I am very close to doing.

Comment: I've got a problem quite similar. My presenter only needs to be bound to one activity. However, I need to pass the presenter from one instance to another of the same activity when it's destroyed and recreated by the system (e.g. when the screen is rotated).

Comment: @Milack - In the end I used fragments instead of activities, created the presenter in the main activity, and just had a single IView, implemented by the activity and had all the UI features pass through to the appropriate fragments. Then there is nothing to pass around. I left this question open in the hope that someone might clarify a bit how to practically implement MVP on Android.